# Why when I JOIN to a casted field in an index view, the execution plan warns about "type conversion in expression"?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, materialized-view, type-conversion, warning

I thought an indexed view was materialized and therefor stored on disk. If that's the case, I would've thought that any type conversions I'm doing in the view would materialize as that datatype on disk and I wouldn't have to worry about casting issues while using those fields in JOIN and WHERE predicates against the view.

Why is this not so?

[image: Type Conversion in Expression Warning]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An indexed view is expanded during query compilation unless the `NOEXPAND` table hint is used. The warning is generated on that expansion. In Enterprise Edition, the optimizer *may* later match the expansion back to the materialized view. This is a cost-based decision.

In anything other than Enterprise Edition (or equivalent) [you **must** use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008/dd171921(v=sql.100)#optimizer-considerations) a `NOEXPAND` hint to use the index(es) on a materialized view.

In Enterprise Edition, there are still good reasons to use the `NOEXPAND` hint:

- [Indexed Views and Statistics](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/sql-plan/indexed-views-and-statistics)
- [Another Reason to Use NOEXPAND hints in Enterprise Edition](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/12/sql-performance/noexpand-hints)